# Insert text into particular location in PDF

Tags: python, geospatial-pdf

I have a geospatial PDF in which coordinates data is encoded and I have UTM X and UTM Y available I want to insert the text 'Hello world' at that location but I don't know how to do it.

I tried using different Python libraries but don't know how to do it. I know I can insert text at particular pixels of a PDF using this code which I tried. How can I solve this issue?

```py
import io
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter

input_pdf = PdfReader(open('geo.pdf', 'rb'))

buffer = io.BytesIO()
c = canvas.Canvas(buffer)
c.drawString(165.546086513, 490.0217355398, "Hello, World!")
c.save()
buffer.seek(0)


text_pdf = PdfReader(buffer)

output_pdf = PdfWriter()
for i in range(len(input_pdf.pages)):
    page = input_pdf.pages[i]
    if i == 0:
        page.merge_page(text_pdf.pages[0])
    output_pdf.add_page(page)

with open('output.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    output_pdf.write(f)
```

Comment: has been asnwered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75928826/how-to-insert-a-text-into-particular-location-in-pdf)

Comment: @JorjMcKie That is for to place text at particular pixels but i want to place text at the particular coordinates which are geo graphical coordinates as i have a geo referenced pdf and i have UTM  X and UTM Y availble. That is also my question but i thought this exchange platform is more good to  place this type of question

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit of a late reply, but I'm dealing with this problem using the [LaTeX package tikz](https://tikz.dev).
In particular, elements called [nodes](https://tikz.dev/gd-usage-tikz) are useful here.

Example of a [result file](https://www.alamy.com/nevada-state-of-united-states-of-america-solid-color-shape-locations-and-names-of-major-cities-of-the-region-corner-%20auxiliary-location-maps-image546016377.html)

Of course, you have to translate the coordinates into points, but I expect it's not a problem.

You can also paste text into a **PDF** using **Ghostscript**, with the command:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=output.pdf -c "<< /EndPage { 2 eq { pop false } { gsave /NimbusMonoPS-Bold 50 selectfont 200 100 moveto (Sample) show grestore true } ifelse } bind >> setpagedevice" -f input.pdf
```